# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'list'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Once I run the below code, I get the following error:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'list'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I cannot find the reason for the warning.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Form from './Form';

const App = () => {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState('pizza');
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const submitSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTerm(e.target.elements.receiptName.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async term => {
      const api_url = 'https://www.food2fork.com/api';
      const api_key = '<MY API KEY>';

      const response = await axios.get(
        `${api_url}/search?key=${api_key}&q=${term}&count=5`
      );

      setList(response.data.recipes);
      console.log(list);
    })(term);
  }, [term]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1 className="App-title">Recipe Search</h1>
      </header>
      <Form submitSearch={submitSearch} />
      {term}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Inside your useEffect you are logging `list`:

```
console.log(list);
```

So you either need to remove the above line, or add `list` to the useEffect dependencies at the end.
so change this line

```
}, [term]);
```

to

```
}, [term, list]);
```

Comment: Is it a bad practice to have variables inside useEffect but not adding them in the dependencies array? For example when you use empty dependencies array to simulate componentDidMount

Comment: Well that depends a bit. From the official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html adding an empty array is telling React that the hook is not dependent on any props or state changes. So you can leave them out if you are a 100% sure that the values of those variables won't change later on (for instance because they are not derived from state or a prop), or when you simply don't care for those changes in the hook that you write.

Answer (score 33):

You can disable the lint warning by writing:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [term]);
```

Comment: This didn't disable the warning.

Answer (score 15):

You can disable this by inserting a comment

**// eslint-disable-next-line**

Comment: This didn't disable the warning.

Comment: Worked for me. The comment needs to be added right above the line with the empty dependency list.

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri for both comments... this will definitely disable the warning. and @all: I NEVER EVER will approve a `disable-next-line` in a review. It means "I don't care about what my code is doing, so I resign". That's not how to write code. This rule only exists to ...good question... ah: if you're generating code (e.g. AST) and generate random warnings ^^ can't think of any useful scenario otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

The `dependency array` - it's the second optional parameter in the `useEffect` function. React will recall function defined in the first parameter of `useEffect` function if parameters inside `dependency array` will changed from the previous render.

Then you doesn't need to place `list` variable inside `dependency array`.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // do some

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [term]);
```

Answer (score 5):

This warning comes beacuse you have a state 'list' being used inside useEffect. So react warns you that 'list' is not added to dependency so any changes to 'list' state won't trigger this effect to run again.
You can find more help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425444/can-we-use-a-function-as-second-arguments-in-useeffect)