# Can we use a function as second arguments in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have below function:

```
function handleEnterPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      if (value !== "") {
        let toAdd = true;
        chips.forEach(chip => {
          if (chip.value === value) {
            toAdd = false;
          }
        });
        if (toAdd) {
          let chipsCopy = [...chips, { value, isDisabled: false }];
          setChips(chipsCopy);
        }
      }
      setValue("");
    }
  }
```

and I have below `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.addEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
    return () =>
      inputRef.current.removeEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
  }, [value]);
```

Now react gives me a warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency 'handleEnterPress'.

What difference does it make when we add `handleEnterPress` in second argument array?

Answer (score 5):

> What difference does it make when we add handleEnterPress in second argument array.

For you? Cleaner code without warnings.
For React? Is just the way it works with `useEffect`.

To remove this warning, you need to add `handleEnterPress` to the dependency array of the `useEEfect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.addEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
    return () =>
      inputRef.current.removeEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
  }, [value, handleEnterPress]);
```

The reason why you need this, is because react can't know what `handleEnterPress` do, or what is. What if `handleEnterPress` is a variable and it's value have changed? If you change `handleEnterPress` you will need to 'run' the effect again, but if you only use `[value]`, it won't 'run' when `handleEnterPress` changes. In your case, maybe it will never change, but react can't know that, so... it tells you to add as a dependency.

e.g.

1 . In `useEffect`, you add an event listener.

```
inputRef.current.addEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
```

2. But then you change the value of `handleEnterPress` some how (many this is not your case but it's something expected from `useEffect`)
   And you don't have `handleEnterPress` in the dependency of `useEffect`, so it don't run the effect.
3. Then `value` changes and the cleanup of the effect happens

   ```
   () => inputRef.current.removeEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
   ```

In this part you will try to remove `handleEnterPress` with the new value of the `handleEnterPress`, but not the one in the first step, so you are trying to remove an event listener that don't exists.

The first `handleEnterPress` containing the old values will never be removed.

**This is bad and it's the reason why you need to add `handleEnterPress` as a dependency**

## Edit:

When `chips` change, `handleEnterPress` changes too, and because you don't add `handleEnterPress` to the depéndency array, you will always have the old value of `handleEnterPress` and also the old value of `chips`.

Your case is explained in my answer, is the case where `handleEnterPress` changes, but the event listener still have the old value of `handleEnterPress`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But actually in my case if you see handleEnterPress function, I am using a react state 'chips' in there. So when I am not adding this function to the second argument array of useEffect, any change in 'chips' that is happening in other side effects is not reflected in this function. It is takin the same old value of chips. Can you help?

Comment: @harshit Check my edit. You think this isn't your case, but acctually it is, when `chips` change, `handleEnterPress` changes too. That is why you need to add `handleEnterPress` as a dependency, otherwise, it will reference the old value of `chips`

Comment: But as far as I know in Hooks on every render handleEnterPress will be re-decalred and it will get the updated value of chips and my effect will also run when ''value" changes. So again a new listener will get attached with the updated 'chips' value.
FYI: value of state 'value' is changing in my case.

Comment: Because you don't add `handleEnterPress` to the dependecy, you never clean the first `handleEnterPress` you added, so the old value will be always there.  `handleEnterPress` will be update on every render. but the first `inputRef.current.addEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);` will never be cleaned correctly because `handleEnterPress` will have changed. And again, I explain this in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I found a better approach to do this 
We can put the function 'handleEnterPress' function inside useEffect itself:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function handleEnterPress(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        if (value !== "") {
          let toAdd = true;
          chips.forEach(chip => {
            if (chip.value.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()) {
              toAdd = false;
            }
          });
          if (toAdd) {
            let chipsCopy = [...chips, { value, isDisabled: false }];
            setChips(chipsCopy);
          }
        }
        setValue("");
      }
    }
    inputRef.current.addEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
    return () =>
      inputRef.current.removeEventListener("keyup", handleEnterPress);
  }, [value, chips]);
```