# Data Fetching with React using useEffect

Tags: reactjs

What I am trying to do is when the user click the edit button, this will send him to a new page where he can modify the info he already entered. The problem I am facing is that the new page is not showing the data previously entered, so that the user can make his changes. Also, the submit button to send those changes is not working. These are the errors I am getting: src\components\RestaurantList.jsx
Line 25:8:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setRestaurants'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
Line 31:19:  'response' is assigned a value but never used                                                                      no-unused-vars

src\components\UpdateRestaurant.jsx
Line 9:12:  'restaurants' is assigned a value but never used                                                         no-unused-vars
Line 38:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'code'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

My code for the component I am working on:

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import RestaurantFinder from '../apis/RestaurantFinder';
import { RestaurantsContext } from '../context/RestaurantsContext';

const UpdateRestaurant = (props) => {

    const {code} = useParams();
    const {restaurants} = useContext(RestaurantsContext);
    let history = useHistory();

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [value, setValue] = useState ("");
    const [strain, setStrain] = useState ("");
    const [weight, setWeight] = useState ("");
    const [authors, setAuthors] = useState ("");
    const [number, setNumber] = useState ("");
    const [page, setPage] = useState ("");
    const [date, setDate] = useState ("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await RestaurantFinder.get(`/${code}`);
            console.log(response.data.data);
            setName(response.data.data.restaurant.name);
            setValue(response.data.data.restaurant.value);
            setStrain(response.data.data.restaurant.strain);
            setWeight(response.data.data.restaurant.weight);
            setAuthors(response.data.data.restaurant.authors);
            setNumber(response.data.data.restaurant.number);
            setPage(response.data.data.restaurant.page);
            setDate(response.data.data.restaurant.date);
            
           
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);


    const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const updatedRestaurant = await RestaurantFinder.put(`/${code}`, {
            name,
            value,
            strain,
            weight,
            authors,
            number,
            page,
            date,  
            
        });
        console.log(updatedRestaurant);
        history.push("/");
        
    };


    return (
        <div>
            
            <form action="">

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                    <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} code="name" className="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Value">Value</label>
                    <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} code="value" className="form-control" type="float" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Strain">Strain</label>
                    <input value={strain} onChange={(e) => setStrain(e.target.value)} code="strain" className="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Weight">Weight</label>
                    <input value={weight} onChange={(e) => setWeight(e.target.value)} code="weight" className="form-control" type="float" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Author">Author</label>
                    <input value={authors} onChange={(e) => setAuthors(e.target.value)} code="authors" className="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Number">Number</label>
                    <input value={number} onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)} code="number" className="form-control" type="number" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="Page">Page</label>
                    <input value={page} onChange={(e) => setPage(e.target.value)} code="page" className="form-control" type="number" />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="date">Date</label>
                    <input value={date} onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)} code="date" className="form-control" type="number" />
                </div>

                <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </form> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default UpdateRestaurant
```

Comment: For the errors regarding dependencies, see this other question and its answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938884/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-list as well as the API documentation for `useEffect`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: the things you mentioned above are not errors, just warnings and they can't cause any problems related to your issue .

Answer (score 1):

for reusable code, it may be best to just do something like this.

This is probably not the answer, but I hope it helps you find out the answer.

```
        const [data, setData ] = useState({restraunt.loaded:"false"});
    
             useEffect(() => {
    
  const fetch = async () => {
                        const response = await RestaurantFinder.get(`/${code}`);
                        console.log(response.data.data);
               setData({...response.data.data, restraunt.loaded:"true"});               
                    };
fetch();
            },[Data.restraunt.loaded])
        


           const {name, value , page, loaded } = Data.restaurant;

return (
        <div><h1>{loaded}</h1>
            </div>
)
```

If it shows loaded as false then you know it is because of the data not loading.