# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'refreshDisplay'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs

I'm a fairly new React dev and I've an issue with my code. I've multiples warnings about missing dependencies when I use useEffect(() => {}, []). I'm following a react training (the code below is an extract from my final project) but the courses's quality seems to be bad. Unfortunately, I've to create my own website thanks to React with all the knowledge learned in 3 monthes. Most of examples given during this training contain useEffect with empty dependency. Is it a bad practice ?

When I inspect in Chrome, I've many warnings saying "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: ''. Either include it or remove the dependency array" but I don't know why. Could you help me please ?

Here is my code :

````
import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from "react"

import {getAllShopOpinions} from "../../api/shopOpinions"
import {convertDate} from "../../utils/utils"
import {config} from "../../config/config"
import {deleteOpinion} from "../../api/shopOpinions"

//Imports des composants de l'UI externes
import Header from "../headers/header"
import HeaderPages from "../headers/headerPages"
import Footer from "../footer"
import AdminMenu from "../../components/adminMenu"

//Imports depuis la librairie MaterialUI
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles"
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete'

const AdminShopOpinions = (props) => {

    const headerTitle ="Administration"
    const headerBreadcrumbs = [{value: "Accueil", link:"/"},{value: "Administration", link:"/admin"},{value: "Avis", link:null}]

    const [displayedShopOpinions, setDisplayedShopOpinions] = useState([])

    //Définition des styles MaterialUI
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        deleteBtn:{
            color:"#cc0e00"
        }
        }));
        
    const classes = useStyles();

    //Au chargement de la page
    useEffect(() => {
        refreshDisplay()
    }, [])

    const refreshDisplay = () => {
        getAllShopOpinions()
        .then(shopOpinionsDB => {
            setDisplayedShopOpinions([])
            loadDisplayedShopOpinions(shopOpinionsDB)
        })
    }

    const deleteDisplayedOpinion = (id, index) => {
        deleteOpinion(id)
        .then(response => {
            refreshDisplay()
        })
    }

    //Chargement des avis à afficher
    const loadDisplayedShopOpinions = (shopOpinions) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < shopOpinions.length; i++){
            setDisplayedShopOpinions(displayedShopOpinions => [...displayedShopOpinions, 
                <article key={shopOpinions[i].id} className="shop-opinion-item">
                    <section className="shop-opinion-infos">
                        <p>" {shopOpinions[i].comment} "</p>
                        <p>Auteur : <em>{shopOpinions[i].first_name} {shopOpinions[i].last_name}</em></p>
                        <p><em>le {convertDate(shopOpinions[i].creation_timestamp)}</em></p>
                    </section>
                    {shopOpinions[i].pict_url &&
                    <section className="shop-opinion-pict">
                        <img src={config.shop_opinion_pict_url + shopOpinions[i].pict_url} alt={"illustration"+shopOpinions[i].id}/>
                    </section>}
                    <Button className={classes.deleteBtn} onClick={(e) => {deleteDisplayedOpinion(shopOpinions[i].id, i)}}><DeleteIcon /></Button>
                </article>])
        }
    }

    //Fonction d'affichage des avis
    const showDisplayedShopOpinions = () => {
        return(
            <section className="shop-opinions-container">
                {displayedShopOpinions.length > 0 ? displayedShopOpinions : <p>Aucun avis à afficher</p>}
            </section>
        )
    }

    return (
        <section className="root">
                <Header />
                <HeaderPages headerTitle={headerTitle} headerBreadcrumbs={headerBreadcrumbs}/>
                <section className="admin-container">
                    <AdminMenu />
 
                    <section className="admin-content">
                        <h4>Gestion des avis</h4>
                        {showDisplayedShopOpinions()}
                    </section>
                </section>
                <Footer />
        </section>
    )
}

export default AdminShopOpinions```



Thank you in advance and have a nice day :)
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938884/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-list)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bad practice to ignore the linter? Yes, it is. You should just about always add any missing dependencies the linter complains about. An edge case is when you ***specifically*** want an effect to run only on component mount by using an empty dependency array (`[]`).

From what I can tell you are in the "special" case where you want it to run on component mount. You can disable the lint rule specifically for this line.

```
useEffect(() => {
  refreshDisplay();
  // Disable for on component mount
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 
}, []);
```

##### Sidenote

You will want to move the `const useStyles = makeStyles(....)` definition ***outside*** the component so the `useStyles` hook isn't redeclared each render cycle.

Answer (score 0):

refreshDisplay() is a function assinged to a variable, if something changes about the variable, the effect might be outdated.

It's bad practice to ignore the linter so I give you a better thing to do:

You can useCallback() hook to wrap the functions:

```
 const refreshDisplay = useCallback(() => {
        getAllShopOpinions()
        .then(shopOpinionsDB => {
            setDisplayedShopOpinions([])
            loadDisplayedShopOpinions(shopOpinionsDB)
        })
    }, [getAllShopOpinions, setDisplayedShopOpinions, loadDisplayedShopOpinions])
```

It makes sure the function remains the same for all the dependencies.
This code will make an infinity loop because you need to wrap other functions like `getAllShopOpinions` `setDisplayedShopOpinions` `loadDisplayedShopOpinions` with useCallback as well

There are other ways to do it to:

1. Moving function's declarations outside of component then the reference won't change
2. Using useRef() to make sure the reference remains the same

however, the best practice is to useCallback()

Hopefully, that explains your problem