# Accessing firestore functions from React useEffect without dependency warning

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using ReactJS and Google FireStore to create a simple stock portfolio tracking app. How can I access database functions from within useEffect without triggering the warning "React Hook has a missing dependency"? I've tried playing around a bit with useCallback, but no success so far. Or is it ok to ignore these warnings?

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
  useEffect(() => {
    //get user's cost averages from db

    if (props.userStatus) {
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(props.userStatus)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            if (doc.data().portfolio) {
              setCostAverages(doc.data().portfolio);
            }
          }
        });
    }
  }, [props.userStatus]);
```

Warning msg: "React Hook useEffect has missing dependency 'db'

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

The frequent solution to this warning is to add the reference of the Firestore instance to the dependency array of the `useEffect()` hook function. You can check this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938884/) and [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6903) for more details. For your code snippet, the dependency array would need to look like this:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
  useEffect(() => {
    //get user's cost averages from db
    //...
  }, [props.userStatus, db]);
```

According to the documentation, the [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) should include all values used in the effect scope:

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders.

Finally, I found a [detailed guide](https://dennyscott.io/use-effect-dependency-array/#what-is-the-dependency-array) which goes much in depth into this dependency array.